# How to set Azure DevOps custom Work Item Type hierarchy?

Tags: azure-devops, hierarchy

Is there a way to set a hierarchy for custom Work Item Types in Azure DevOps?

We have several custom ones in our company and I have followed the Inherited process tips to create new ones, but still cannot figure out how to set a particular hierarchy?

In other words, how to forbid creating a work item of a certain WIT to be a child of another work item of other WIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DevOps does not support such restrictions. Similar functions are available in the Portfolio backlogs:  [Add a portfolio backlog level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=azure-devops#add-portfolio-backlog).